# Adding a property in an array of objects in a separate array of objecs by id

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have these two array, and I want to push the second array to its parent as an extra property by comparing the `parent id` to `child parentsId`, i've been spending hours to get my desired output, help would be very much appreciated

**first array**

```
const parent = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'john',
        age: 32,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'jane',
        age: 44,
      },
    ];
```

second array

```
const child = [
      {
        parentId: 1,
        name: 'mike',
        age: 5,
      },
      {
        parentId: 2,
        name: 'michelle',
        age: 6,
      },
      {
        parentId: 2,
        name: 'morgan',
        age: 7,
      },
    ];
```

**This is the result that I wanted, so basically the child will be populated to its parent by using parentId**

```
  const parent = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'john',
        age: 32,
        children: [
          {
            parentId: 1,
            name: 'mike',
            age: 5,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'jane',
        age: 44,
        children: [
          {
            parentId: 2,
            name: 'michelle',
            age: 6,
          },
          {
            parentId: 2,
            name: 'morgan',
            age: 7,
          },
        ],
      },
```

Comment: You can try `child.reduce((p,c) => doSomethingWithPandC(p,c), parent)`

Comment: @Redu my javascript is not that great, im sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `.map()`, `.filter()` and spread syntax:

```js
const parent = [{ id: 1, name: "john", age: 32 }, { id: 2, name: "jane", age: 44}];
const child = [{ parentId: 1, name: "mike", age: 5}, { parentId: 2, name: "michelle", age:6}, { parentId: 2, name: "morgan", age: 7}];

const result = parent.map(person => ({
  ...person,
  children: child.filter(({ parentId }) => parentId === person.id)
}));

console.log(result);
```

EDIT: I'm not sure exactly why your question was closed. I wouldn't say that it lacks 'focus'. Perhaps it's because you didn't provide info about *how* you tried to solve the problem, or what errors you ran into. Next time, please provide more information.

Comment: awesome! appreciated!